# breakpoint not every time can hit in DriverEntry()/Unload() function in vs2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, driver, remote-debugging, wdk, kmdf

I set multiple source lines' breakpoints in DriverEntry() and Unload() function. and in target site's device-manager, I operate continuously the driver's stop/restart function, but breakpoints not every time can hit in DriverEntry()/Unload() function. Sometimes breakpoints can hit in DriverEntry()/Unload(), sometimes breakpoints can't hit in DriverEntry()/Unload(). Even if breakpoint can hit on DriverEntry()/Unload()'s certain source line(assume on Line10), when press F5 to contiune to go, it also possible to un-hit on next line line11 on which I also set a breakpoint. About breakpoints' behavior mentioned above, this is normal or nu-normal in visual studio driver development envirnment ??? thanks !

note : Windows 10 pro is installed in target computer, Window 8.1 home is installed in host computer, and visual studio 2015 pro update2 with WDK10 is used via Ethernet network to connect target and host notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your symbols loaded properly?
you can cross check the .sympath, then .reload -f  to reload the driver and check if bp is hitting or not.
Are you loading the correct timestamp of driver, check !lmi 
You can also use sxe ld  - this will break into debugger when driver is loaded into memory.